# How to export a Google Slide to a pdf in portrait orientation using App Script?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-slides

I know how to export a slide into a pdf using App Script with such a kind of code :

```
folder.createFile(holderFile.getBlob()).setName(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(diplomenumber) + '.pdf');
```

but the problem is that the pdf generated is in landscape orientation instead of portrait orientation even if my slide is in portrait orientation.

So I was wondering if there is a solution to get the pdf generated from Google Slides in portrait orientation using App Script.

Thanks for any good advices.

Comment: I cannot understand `the problem is that the pdf generated is in landscape orientation instead of portrait orientation even if my slide is in portrait orientation.`. For example, when you set the slide page size as 10cm x 20cm (width x height), the PDF is exported 20cm x 10cm. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike : Yes it is exactly the problem I am facing so any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: This is not reproducible on my side, when I export the slide as pdf, it exports the same format as the settings in `File > Page Setup`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, when I tested using a sample Google Slides with 10cm x 20cm (width x height) and exported as a PDF file using `folder.createFile(holderFile.getBlob())`, the exported PDF file is 10cm x 20cm (width x height). Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. So, in this case, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide your whole script and the detailed flow? By this, I would like to confirm it.